# how to calculate distance traveled for indoor navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, accelerometer

I would like to use accelerometer to detect distance traveled for indoor distance detection (sorry if this is a silly question I am very new to flutter)

I found code that will let me present accelerometer data but not save it.

https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-use-device-sensors-in-flutter-gyroscope-proximity/

this of course is not my own code its just I found this and I would like to use the data recorded and calculated the distance traveled.

Comment: wellcome to stackoverflow, it's no a silly question ,it a deep one , you can check   [Detecting distance moved by accelerometer? - Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/25529/detecting-distance-moved-by-accelerometer?newreg=0087a0b0c10f4be2b872b8742341fcd9)

Comment: thank you for your comment but my issue was not how to find the distance based on acceleration. My question was how do I collect the data from the accelerometer that I have link above. That is the issue I have spent two weeks trying to figure out. Any help on this will be immensely appreciated.

Comment: The example is clear , I just tried it , is it ***not*** ***compiling*** and ***running***  for you ?

Comment: So how would I save the accelerometer data to calculate the velocity for starters? (from there it would be easy enough to calculate distance)

Comment: oh and I forgot to specify yes, I can run and compile the code i just don't know how to save the accelerometer data so i can use it to calculate velocity as specified in previous comment

Comment: wil the app be open or in the background

Comment: either would work

Comment: but background is probably better. but I can work with both. I just don't know how to do either

Answer (score 0):

So this issue is not very solvable in Dart/Flutter.
The better way to do this app is with Java.
With a Java app simply find an accelerometer app and through that you can calculate speed and distance. The difference is that the in Java the stream that is used in Dart is a repeating function. In that function calculations can be conducted.